# Titanium "addEventListener" is called multiple times but I only need it once

Tags: android, iphone, titanium

I am using this code in Titanium SDK 3.0.0.GA when I click on any button (left_btn or right_btn) once the eventListener(`scrollView.addEventListener('scroll',function(){});`) is called multiple times.

How can I fix this issue?

```
right_btn.addEventListener('singletap', function() {
       scrollView.scrollToView(scrollView.currentPage + 1);

});
left_btn.addEventListener('singletap', function() {
    scrollView.scrollToView(scrollView.currentPage - 1);
});

scrollView.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        alert("scroll view");
});
```

Please, help me!
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use removeEventListener to remove event after doing what you want in event function.

```
function scrollEvent() {
    alert('scroll view');
    scrollView.removeEventListener('scroll', this);
}

scrollView.addEventListener('scroll', scrollEvent);
```

Or declare a temporary boolean variable to determine if event is already fired.

```
var fired = false;
scrollView.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
    if (!fired) {
        alert('scroll view');
        fired = true;
    }
});
```